# How to display data from the Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am storing my data in Vuex as you see in the picture:

[image]

And product object is like this:

[image]

My aim is to get the variation '1' and find it in the product object and display the price_excl_vat.

So here is my mutations file:

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = (state, {product, variation, amount}) => {
    let productInCart = state.cart.find(item => {
        return item.product.id === product.id;
    });
    if(productInCart) {
        productInCart.amount += amount;
        return;
    }
    state.cart.push({
        product,
        variation,
        amount
    })
}
```

And Cart component:

```
<template>
    <div
        class="dropdown-menu cart"
        aria-labelledby="triggerId"
    >
        <div v-if="cart.length != 0" class="inner-cart">
            <div v-for="item in cart" :key="item.product.id">

                <div class="cart-items">
                    <div>
                        <strong>{{ item.product.attributes.name }}</strong>
                        <br/> {{ item.amount }} x € //price needs to be here
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="remove" @click.prevent="removeProductFromCart(item.product)">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div class="cart-items-total">
                <span>Total: {{cartTotalPrice}}</span>
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="clearCartItems()">Clear Cart</a>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <router-link :to="{name: 'order'}" class="btn button-secondary">Go To Cart</router-link>
        </div>
        <div v-else class="inner-cart">
            <div class="cart-items no-item">
                <i class="fas fa-frown-open"></i>
                <div class="text">ES BEFINDEN SICH KEINE PRODUKTE IM WARENKORB.</div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <router-link :to="{name: 'alle-tickets'}" class="btn button-secondary">ALL TICKETS</router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    computed: {
        cart() {
            return this.$store.state.cart;
        },
        cartTotalPrice() {
            return this.$store.getters.cartTotalPrice;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch('getCartItems')
    }
};
</script>
```

The question might be long a bit and I am new to Vuex, so if you can help me with this I would be really glad. And let me know if you have more details.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you.

You could define a getter in your store like so:

```js
getters: {
  getVariation: (state) => (variationNumber) => {
    return state.cart.find((item) => item.variation === variationNumber);
  }
}
```

Than in your component you can need is to call your getter like this:

```js
this.$store.getters.getVariation(1);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or this is more want you was looking for.

```js
getters: {
  getVariation: (state) => (id) => {
    let product = state.cart.find((item) => item.variation === id).product;
    return product.variations.find((variation) => variation.id === id);
  }
}
```

```js
this.$store.getters.getVariation(1).price_excl_vat;
```

I hope this is what you want achieve and my explanation is clear enough.

Cheers

Comment: [Getter Documentation](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

Comment: @Lars first of all, thank you for your answer. I am trying to apply the second one because it fits into my stiation. But I am getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')"

found in

Comment: Also, to make it more clear what I am trying to do is to return the variations inside of the product because there might be several variations inside of the product and I want to show the price_excl_vat if a variation of the state is in product.attributes.variations

Comment: In which line to you get the error? In `let product = state.cart.find((item) => item.variation === id).product;` or in `product.variations.find((variation) => variation.id === id)`?

Comment: Maybe you could share a vue codepen?